# Fitting Binomial Distribution in R using data with varying sample sizes

Tags: r, statistics

I have some data that looks like this:

```
    x    y
1:  3    1
2:  6    1
3:  1    0
4: 31    8
5:  1    0
---
```

(Edit: if it helps, here are sample vectors for x and y

```
    x = c(3, 6, 1, 31, 1, 18, 73, 29, 2, 1)

    y = c(1, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

The column on the left (x) is my sample size, and the column on the right (y) is the number successes that occur in each sample.

I would like to fit these data using a binomial distribution in order to find the probability of a success (p).  All examples for fitting a binomial distribution that I've found so far assume a constant sample size (n) across all data points, but here I have varying sample sizes.

1. How do I fit data like these, with varying sample sizes, to a binomial distribution?  The desired outcome is p, the probability of observing a success in a sample size of 1.
2. How do I accomplish a fit like this using R?

(Edit #2: Response below outlines solution and related R code if I assume that the events observed in each sample can be assumed to be independent, in addition to assuming that the samples themselves are also independent.  This works for my data - thanks!)

Comment: Are all the row related to the exact same event? Are the row independent from each other? Is the sample size also a random variable to model?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the desired output is here. Are there no other covariates? also, be sure to share sample data in a  [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Each row is an observation of a different event, and each row is independent from each other row.  The sample size is not a random variable.

The desired output is p, the probability of success in the binomial distribution.  There are no other covariates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calculating the empirical probability of success

```
x <- c(3, 6, 1, 31, 1, 18, 73, 29, 2, 1)
y <-  c(1, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0)

avr.sample <- mean(x)
avr.success <- mean(y)

p <- avr.success/avr.sample
[1] 0.1151515
```

Or using `binom.test`

```
z <- x-y # number of fails
binom.test(x = c(sum(y), sum(z)))
Exact binomial test

data:  c(sum(y), sum(z))
number of successes = 19, number of trials = 165, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
0.07077061 0.17397215
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.1151515
```

**However**, this assumes that:

1. The events corresponding to the rows are independent from each other
2. The events in the same row are independent from each other as well

This means in every iteration `k` of the experiment (i.e. row of `x`) we execute an action such as throwing `x[k]` **identical** dices (not necessarily fair dices) and success would mean to get a given (predetermined) number `n` in `1:6`.

If we supposed that that above results were achieved when trying to get a `1` when throwing `x[k]` dices  in every iteration `k`, then one could say that the empirical probability of getting a `1` is (~) `0.1151515`.

In the end, the distribution in question would be `B(sum(x), p)`.

**PS:** In the above illustration, the dices are identical to each other not only in any given iteration but across all iterations.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(bbmle)

x = c(3, 6, 1, 31, 1, 18, 73, 29, 2, 1)
y = c(1, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0)

mf = function(prob, x, size){
  -sum(dbinom(x, size, prob, log=TRUE))
}

m1 = mle2(mf, start=list(prob=0.01), data=list(x=y, size=x))
print(m1)
```

Coefficients:
prob
0.1151535

Log-likelihood: -13.47